# Flink uses rebalance when the two operator's parallelism are different

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying flink 1.12.0,

I noticed that flink will automatically add `relabance` between operators that are using different parallism. Following is an example, the events from source operator will be sent to the downstream map/sink operator in round-robin fasion:

`env.addSource(...).setParallesim(1).map(...).addSink(..).setParallesim(3)`

I would ask where the flink source code adds this trick, I look into the code,but didn't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways that either rebalancing or rescaling can occur within the pipeline to handle scenarios between two operators with incongruent parallelism. You can see this defined within the base [`DataStream<T>`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0915c9850d861165e283acc0f60545cd836f0567/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.java) class itself:

```
/**
 * Sets the partitioning of the {@link DataStream} so that the output elements are distributed
 * evenly to instances of the next operation in a round-robin fashion.
 *
 * @return The DataStream with rebalance partitioning set.
 */
public DataStream<T> rebalance() {
    return setConnectionType(new RebalancePartitioner<T>());
}

/**
 * Sets the partitioning of the {@link DataStream} so that the output elements are distributed
 * evenly to a subset of instances of the next operation in a round-robin fashion.
 *
 * <p>The subset of downstream operations to which the upstream operation sends elements depends
 * on the degree of parallelism of both the upstream and downstream operation. For example, if
 * the upstream operation has parallelism 2 and the downstream operation has parallelism 4, then
 * one upstream operation would distribute elements to two downstream operations while the other
 * upstream operation would distribute to the other two downstream operations. If, on the other
 * hand, the downstream operation has parallelism 2 while the upstream operation has parallelism
 * 4 then two upstream operations will distribute to one downstream operation while the other
 * two upstream operations will distribute to the other downstream operations.
 *
 * <p>In cases where the different parallelisms are not multiples of each other one or several
 * downstream operations will have a differing number of inputs from upstream operations.
 *
 * @return The DataStream with rescale partitioning set.
 */
@PublicEvolving
public DataStream<T> rescale() {
    return setConnectionType(new RescalePartitioner<T>());
}
```

Each of these use the [`RebalancePartitioner`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/af5719993dd8d5164e03171810bbd709523d0927/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/partitioner/RebalancePartitioner.java) and [`RescalePartitioner`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/af5719993dd8d5164e03171810bbd709523d0927/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/partitioner/RescalePartitioner.java) respectively. However, if you dig around a bit more, you can see this being referenced in the [`StreamGraph`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0915c9850d861165e283acc0f60545cd836f0567/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/graph/StreamGraph.java), which is responsible for constructing the DAG that Flink executes within the [`createActualEdge()`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/0915c9850d861165e283acc0f60545cd836f0567/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/graph/StreamGraph.java#L680-L699) call:

```
// If no partitioner was specified and the parallelism of upstream and downstream
// operator matches use forward partitioning, use rebalance otherwise.
if (partitioner == null
        && upstreamNode.getParallelism() == downstreamNode.getParallelism()) {
    partitioner =
        dynamic ? new ForwardForUnspecifiedPartitioner<>() : new ForwardPartitioner<>();
} else if (partitioner == null) {
    partitioner = new RebalancePartitioner<Object>();
}
```

This will handle evaluating the nodes in the graph (operators) and examining their respective levels of parallelism and rebalancing if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @rion-williams for the helpful answer, I understand and find the source code